# trading pet system between players (javascript, php...)

Tags: system, trading

Hi everyone and sorry in advance for my horrible english.
I'm making an adoptable pet site project and I want to built a system where players can exchange their creatures between them. But my problem ? I don't know where to start. With my DB or my DOM I don't kwow at all. How can I stock the creatures (who already exists) and offers to the other.

I have some bases in javascripts and php, it's just the way I can make it who sound wrong on my brain.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to realize that. I will give you a basic idea of a possible software architecture.

1. A database stores all the information. So you might think about [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). In your case, *creatures* and *players* are entities. You can also create an entity to connect both and realize the ownership of those *creatures*. Let's call it *creature_player_assignments*. This means, that you could assign N creatures to M players. Or the other way around: M players can have N creatures. (`n:m` relationship). You don't need it, if you only want to assign a creature to only one player. In this case you could direclty assign the creature to a player by storing something unique from the player in the creature (like the player ID or something). So, N creatures are assigned to 1 player, or the other way around: One player can have multiple creatures (`1:n` relationship).
2. A server connects to the database and gets the information you need. You can use PHP and some libraries to do so.
3. The same server implements an API to make the information accessible from outside. Think about a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service or something.
4. The client sends requests to the server using the implemented API. You could do that using JavaScript and [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

In the end it is up to you, to design the architecture. Try to think about your software first and plan it before you start smashing the keyboard.